# Python concatanate sheets and add sheet specific values to results

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel workbook with x number of sheets that follows the same format

Sheet 1

```
|         A      |   B   |   c   |   D   |   E   |   F
1
2    Comp Name: XYZ
3    Client Name |   Id  |   val
4      Ben            1       50
5      Tom            2       43
6      Yin            3       12
```

Sheet 2

```
|         A      |   B   |   c   |   D   |   E   |   F
1
2    Comp Name: ABC
3    Client Name |   Id  |   val
4      Liam           4       98
5      Jin            5       23
6      Paul           6       55
```

...

Sheet x

```
|         A      |   B   |   c   |   D   |   E   |   F
1
2    Comp Name: PQR
3    Client Name |   Id  |   val
4      Abba           7       41
5      Ram            8       56
6      Mick           9       77
```

I'm attempting to concatenate the sheets as a data-frame while also adding the company name as another column.
I googled and figured out how I can concatenate which is

```
 pd.concat(pd.read_excel(path, skiprows=range(1, 2),  sheet_name=None, usecols='A:C',header=1), ignore_index=True)
```

This provides the concatenated rows.

But I'm stuck at the point where I need to get the company name as another column for each row of the sheet. My idea is that I loop through the results from read_excel, get the A2 value and store it as another new column for that sheet.
The ideal results I'm looking for a data-frame as follows

```
Client Name    |    Id     |     Val     |     Comp Name
     Ben            1            50                XYZ
     Tom            2            43                XYZ                
     Yin            3            12                XYZ
     Liam           4            98                ABC
     Jin            5            23                ABC                
     Paul           6            55                ABC
 ...
     Abba           7            41                PQR
     Ram            8            56                PQR                
     Mick           9            77                PQR
```

I would greatly appreciate a path to the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me -

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: excel_obj = pd.ExcelFile("clients.xlsx")
In [3]: sheet_data = []
In [4]: for sheet in excel_obj.sheet_names:
   ...:     df = pd.read_excel(excel_obj, sheet_name=sheet)
   ...:     *_, comp_name = df.iloc[
   ...:         0, 0
   ...:     ].split()  # Assuming that company name has no space, else use a different logic
   ...:     data = df.iloc[2:, :]
   ...:     data.columns = df.iloc[1, :].tolist()
   ...:     data["Comp Name"] = comp_name
   ...:     sheet_data.append(dat
In [5]: pd.concat(sheet_data)
Out[5]:
  Client Name Id val Comp Name
2         Ben  1  50       XYZ
3         Tom  2  43       XYZ
4         Yin  3  12       XYZ
2         Tom  1   7       PQR
3       Jerry  2   9       PQR
4         Mac  3  45       PQR
```